# Fredholm integral equation of the second kind with constant kernel

Tags: integral-equations

I'm trying to read Kress' Linear integral equations, and I'm stuck at the first example. There must be something obvious I'm missing, and to that end, should I read something before this text?

$f(x)=\phi(x)-\int_a^b K(x,y)\phi(y)dy,\quad x\in[a,b]$

For the kernel $K(x,y)=c\neq0\quad\forall x,y\in[a,b]$

The solution is
$\phi=f+\frac{c}{1-c(b-a)}\int_a^bf(y)dy$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $K(x,y)=c$, then
$$
f(x)=\phi(x)-cI, \tag{1}
$$
where $I:=\int_a^b\phi(y)\,dy$. Integrating both sides of $(1)$ yields
$$
\int_a^bf(x)\,dx=\int_a^b[\phi(x)-cI]\,dx=I-cI(b-a). \tag{2}
$$
Solving $(2)$ for $I$ and plugging the result in $(1)$, one finally obtains
$$
\phi(x)=f(x)+\frac{c}{1-c(b-a)}\int_a^bf(y)\,dy. \tag{3}
$$

Comment: The last part of equation 3 I'm unclear, I guess the point is f is a single variable function and therefore the integral from a to b of f(x) dx is the same as the integral from a to b of f(y) dy. So the change of variable at the last moment is probably to avoid confusion that the last term is just constant?

Comment: thank you. That was the part that was hanging me up.

Answer (score 0):

You can always substitute $\phi$ in the equation to verify that it is a solution. But I believe you want to know how to obtain the solution. Here is one way:

Rewrite the equation as
$$
\phi(x) = f(x) + c\int_a^b \phi(y) dy.
$$
Now substitute this expression for $\phi$ inside the integral, that is
$$
\phi(x) = f(x) + c \int_a^b \left( f(y) + c\int_a^b \phi(z) dz \right) dy,
$$
which is the same as
$$
\phi(x) = f(x) + c\int_a^b f(y) dy + c^2(b-a) \int_a^b \phi(y) dy.
$$
Now we can replace $c\int_a^b \phi(y) dy$ by $\phi(x)-f(x)$, and hence we obtain
$$
\phi(x) = f(x) + c\int_a^b f(y) dy + c(b-a)(\phi(x)-f(x)),
$$
and after some simple manipulations this gives
$$
\phi(x) = f(x) + \frac{c}{1-c(b-a)}\int_a^b f(y) dy.
$$

For the other question, that depends on your background, but I'm not an specialist in integral equations, and I haven't read the book either.